# I have successfully enlisted a user in cohort via core_cohort_add_cohort_members but getting a warning

Tags: drupal, moodle

I have successfuly enlisted a user in moodle cohort using core_cohort_add_cohort_members but i am getting a warning in response.Can anybody help me remoce this warning.

Here is the warning i get.
{"warnings":[]}

Here is my code

```
     $fname = 'core_cohort_add_cohort_members';

        /// Paramètres
        $member = new stdClass();
        $member->cohorttype[type]='id';
        $member->cohorttype[value]=2;
        $member->usertype[type]='id';
        $member->usertype[value]=8;

        $members = array($member);
        $par = array('members' => $members);
         $rest_format = 'json';

         $Serve_Url = 'localhost/moodle' . '/webservice/rest/server.php'. '?wstoken=' . '72f102312fff135cbb4a301d9c7839ae' .'&wsfunction='. $fname;
        require_once('curl.inc');
         $Rest_format = ($rest_format == 'json') ? '&moodlewsrestformat=' . $rest_format : '';
        $curl = new curl;
        //if rest format == 'xml', then we do not add the param for backward compatibility with Moodle < 2.2
        $rep = $curl->post($Serve_Url.$Rest_format, $par);
        dpm($rep);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warnings array is empty in your example reply.
If you want to detect this more verbosely, you can always just json_decode() the reply. You should see an empty array there.

So I think it's working just as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the keys into strings i.e

```
    $member->cohorttype["type"]='id';
    $member->cohorttype["value"]=2;
    $member->usertype["type"]='id';
    $member->usertype["value"]=8;
```

Mainly because newer versions of PHP may cause real exceptions because of

> unidentified variables(type and value)

That aside as [Sebastian Berm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3941212/sebastian-berm) stated empty warnings array means no problem